# Is "fishing rode" an English word?

Tags: meaning

Yesterday, I saw a document said that "**Fishing rode**". I'm confused. I know "**fishing rod**" but does the word "**fishing rode** an English word?

P/S: The sentence that contains the word **Fishing rode**:

> **Fishing rode** and bucket are things that every angler needs to have, from the Amateurs to the Professionals.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: without more context, we can't really help you.

Comment: Seemingly only in Google advertisers' hopeful pitches to folks who can't spell.

Comment: There is a noun *rode* which is a nautical term for a rope (especially one used to secure a tr

Comment: Please give the surrounding (3 + 3 say) sentences. This is either a misprint or a jargon usage; how can one tell without context?

Answer (score 1):

A ***rode*** is a nautical term for a rope, especially one used to secure an anchor, or trawl. (Oxford Dictionaries). The term is marked as NORTH AMERICAN.

From the OED.

> N. Amer. regional (chiefly New England and Newfoundland). Naut.
>
> A rope, esp. one attached to the anchor of a boat. Cf. roding n.3

Note that the OED mentions nothing about *trawl*. But it gives examples from 1612, the most recent ones being:

> 1963   J. T. Rowland North to Adventure x. 147   With both hooks down
>   and a long scope of rode she should be able to ride out anything.
>
> 1986   J. Feltham Islands of Bonavista Bay 55   On the fishing
>   grounds, the motor boats, like the bullies, were moored with ‘rodes’
>   and grapnels.
>
> 1996   Chesapeake Bay Mag. Sept. 37/2   Carry a good anchor with
>   plenty of chain and rode.

**So the OP's *fishing rode* would seem to have some connection here**.

Comment: And a _trawl_ in this sense is?

Comment: The word ['rove'](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rove) can be the past tense of [reeve](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reeve) in the sense of threading a rope through a ring. Could 'rode' be related to this?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Presumably a trawl net, I would think.

Comment: So is it safe to use it in everyday English? I saw on many sites such as Alibaba they use the word fishing rode sometimes

Comment: @Viettungvuong No, these are surely all typos for *fishing **rods.***

Comment: @tchrist Do Americans call it a fishing rod? I thought that was only us. Don't you talk about a pole, or am I still living in the time of Mark Twain, - H Finn and all that?

Comment: @WS2 Well, I’m sure both terms are used, but it’s always *rod and reel*, never *poll and reel*.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet I did some research before asking the question, and I presume not. But I'm asking because I don't know for certain and would like something better than a presumption.